# Can companies use already-purchased on-prem tooling in the cloud if they want to move to the cloud?

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud

Companies spend a lot of money on tooling for on-prem. But then they often want to move to the cloud for its obvious benefits, but feel limited in their ability to do so since they already invested so much in on-prem tooling. Can companies use already-purchased on-prem tooling in the cloud if they want to move to the cloud? Can they leverage existing licenses and APIs to use those tools in cloud environments like AWS, GCP etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, migrating on-prem solutions to the cloud is often called a “lift and shift” migration, as opposed to building cloud-native systems. But whether this makes sense can depend on the licensing structure. Might be unproblematic for per-user licenses, but could complicate per-CPU licensing. Of course, hardware expenditures are wasted unless a hybrid cloud approach is intended. Administrating cloud-based systems also requires different skills than administrating physical servers.